# Varnish RAM problems

Tags: varnish, varnish-4

I have problems with RAM on servers which use varnish and only it (no other apps there). Each machine has 64GB RAM available for caching and has three separated varnish services for different backends. Currently, the sum of RAM allocated to varnish from all services is 24GB RAM on each server. I want to increase this value up to 48GB (75% of the whole memory available) but I have some problems.

When I tried to allocate 8GB more just for one service (32GB from all), the committed memory got a peak to 70GB RAM(?). What's more, the increased service has restarted a few times after getting 100% ram allocated to its limit (error msg: child not responding to CLI, killing it/died signal=6/Panic message: Assert error in vbf_fetch_thread()). In addition, services use a lot of VSZ (virtual memory size), it that okay?

Answer (score 1):

This could be Transient memory which is uncapped by default and we'll use malloc as storage.
In Transinet stevedore Varnish stores object with a TTL < 10s, therefore if you have many of those that's what you see.

The solution is to either increase the TTLs or cap the Transient storage.

Comment: I have one more question according to varnish and ram. I can observe on the munin tool that one server has active memory ram (which is the sum of memory allocated to varnish services) and uses a lot of "ram cache" when there is a room. The second one does not use almost any ram cache and instead of using that, everything that is left is marked as "unused ram". How to enable cache inside ram?

Comment: Perhaps the second varnish instance is not caching much?

Comment: Nope. Both of then use full of assigned memory limit ram. Statistic RAM usage example: 
1) varnish_1 
- active memory 40GB
- committed memory 60GB
- cache 3GB
- inactive 1GB
- unused 22GB

2) varnish_2 
- active memory 40GB
- committed memory 60GB
- cache 13GB
- inactive 1GB
- unused 4GB

Question: why one uses 3GB ram cache not around 13GB like the other one?

Comment: How do you distribute request between the two caches?

Comment: I use a load balancer HAproxy which distributes requests evenly

Comment: How many objects has each cache?
(varnishstat -1 | grep object)

Comment: Each cache (all services) has about 130-140k objects (it's hard to get accurate value because I have three separated services and varnishstat shows only one - the latest restarted). Munin graph:
Cache_1 ram stats: https://ibb.co/Qm5KrJj
Cache_2 ram stats: https://ibb.co/k2GZCMt
As you can see first cache server's ram does not use RAM cache at all, but the second does. How to fix it?

Comment: How do you load balance between caches?

Comment: In the architecture, there is an HAproxy load balancer. All requests are forced to go through it and it distributes requests to caches evenly.

Answer (score 1):

I've changed jemalloc parameters lg_dirty_mult and lg_chunk. Now I was able to assign 42 GB ram to varnish and committed memory is around 60 GB now. The main varnish task is to cash images and TTL is set to 365d.